# Range loop not working in webscrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written a small web scraper in BS4.With the code I am able to scrape one page at a time,here is the relevant code.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=129867").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

This code scrapes one page but I want to scrape more than one page at a time(a range) so I tried adding this for loop like this.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for ace in range(129867, 129869):

 html = requests.get("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id= {ace}").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
```

Nothing happens when I run the code and I don't even get up any of the usual cryptic messages up hinting at what went wrong.Could it be syntax,or is it something else.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should do everything inside the loop now. And, you are not inserting the `ace` value into the URL and there is an extra space after the `id=`. It might also be a good idea to establish a [web-scraping session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and use the `params` keyword of the `get()` method.

Fixed version:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    for ace in range(129867, 129869):
        url = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx"
        html = session.get(url, params={'id': ace}).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Note this code is still of a blocking nature, it would process the pages one at a time. If you want to speed things up, look into [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework.

Comment: Hi Alecxe ,.thanks for the reply,in the range brackets there are two URL numbers but when run it only brings up one page.ie only one of the url numbers is activated(as you mentioned) is there a way I can scrape several pages.I have migrated from VB and VBA where I would have used the "TO" keyword in the range,but BS seems to do things a lot different.PS started to look at scrapy but that seems a major project in itself

Comment: @moonshadow okay, updated, does it work now? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alecxe.Many thanks for that but whilst it brings up one complete meeting(the first in the range), it then goes a little bit off track by producing a meeting outside the range that contains  corrupted data.

Comment: @moonshadow well, it loops over the range you've provided. In this case, it would iterate over 2 meetings only: `129867` and `129868`..

Comment: Hi Alexce.Interestingly,if I put up the above range(867>869) I get 868 out.It doesn't seem to acknowledge 867 and 869.